# Handler stuck in loop within Android Service

Tags: android, gps, android-service, handler, android-handler

I'm currently trying to do an app that keeps track of the phone through the GPS by using a service. in order to get the GPS to update the coordinates, I need to use a handler within the service. Right now the proble I have is that when the I do the Handler.post, it gets stuck in an loop, and after that, it completely ignores the rest of the service code.

When I was debugging, I found out that the handler was alternating messages between methods but nothing useful came out of it, it was just a loop between the same methods over and over again.

Here's my Service code that includes the handler:

```
   public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
        {
        ctx = ServicioDeFondo.this;
        mHandler = new Handler();


        reportarGPS = new Thread(new Runnable() { public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            gps = new GPSTrack(ctx);
                            latitude = String.valueOf(gps.getLatitude());
                            longitude = String.valueOf(gps.getLongitude());
                        }
                    });

                    Thread.sleep(10000);

                    try {
                        new APISendClass().execute();
                        Thread.sleep(10000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        } });



        reportarGPS.start();

        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

I"ve been stuck here all day, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

With your brief description of the problem, it's hard to understand what the expected behavior is.  You don't explain what `GPSTrack` and `APISendClass` do and what type of objects that are.  You state "it gets stuck in a loop".  It's not clear what "it" is.  With the `while (true)` statement, the thread will loop until cancelled.

Note that `Service` methods, such as `onStartCommand()` run on the main thread.  That means that your `Handler()` constructor associates the handler with the main thread. The runnables you post to that handler run on the main thread.  Is that what you wanted?

Also note that stopping the service by `stopSelf()` or `Context.stopService()` does not kill the thread.  You need to have code to cancel the thread when it is no longer needed. This is often done in `onDestroy()`.

I took the code you posted, replaced the calls to unknown objects with Log statements and ran it.  The logcat output alternated between "Get lat/long" and "APISendClass()".

```
Handler mHandler;
Context ctx;
Thread reportGPS;

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    Log.i("TEST", "onStartCommand()");

    ctx = this;

    // Service methods run on main thread.

    // Handler constructor with no args associates Handler
    // with current thread, which here is the main thread.
    mHandler = new Handler();

    reportGPS = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // This runnable is posted to the main thread.
                            // Is that what you intended?

                            //gps = new GPSTrack(ctx);
                            //latitude = String.valueOf(gps.getLatitude());
                            //longitude = String.valueOf(gps.getLongitude());
                            Log.i("TEST", "Get lat/long");
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(2000);

                    try {
                        //new APISendClass().execute();
                        Log.i("TEST", "APISendClass().execute()");
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    reportGPS.start();

    return START_STICKY;
}
```